# how to delete media image after we delete product in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, php, product-images, mvc

As image plays an important role in page load time,Need to delete image too after delete of product from admin panel in Magento 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some extensions available on a marketplace like an [Image Cleaner](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-image-clean-extension-delete-unused-images.html)

Here you can Find All unused Images for a Product and can be deleted easily

if you want to create one

you can compare all the Images from product gallery table with images in pub/media/catalog/product in this way you can get all unused images

Answer (score 0):

One can delete image file directly from pub/media folder.
or

Open any product > Edit Image > when images wizard opens > Select the Image and Delete Selected.

Comment: NO!!!! when i delete my product, i want product image should also get deleted from pub/media folder.

Comment: please refer to this module- https://github.com/cap340/CleanMedia

Comment: you can just go for this extension Image Clean. perfect for removing unused images.[link](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-image-clean-extension-delete-unused-images.html)